# Sharing Cookies Between SubDomains

Tags: c#, httpclient

I am using an `HttpClient` instance and I would like to know if it is possible to share cookies between subdomains? I am accessing a particular domain, say `test.com`, but their login servers are located at `login.test.com`. This is causing the login cookies which are being generated from the subdomain to not be sent over to the domain.

Is there a simple way I can fix this? Such as an option in the handler or whatever?

Thanks.

Comment: The cookie's domain has to be set to `.test.com` and not `test.com` or `login.test.com`.

Comment: Post it as an answer and I will mark it as correct mate. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To share a cookie over all subdomains, the cookie's domain has to be set to `.test.com` and not `test.com` or `login.test.com`